# Get data in a model formset in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a formset in Django.

I print this formset in the templates as

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

The formset consists of the queryset as forms and a few extra forms. But I need some field values from the queryset that I wont show as forms. How is this possible? It's a queryset with a `prefetch_related`, so the fields aren't actually in the model, but are joined in my queryset.

My models are

```
class Person:
    name = CharField(max_length=200)

class Grade:
    person = ForeignKey(Person)
    grade = IntegerField()
```

My queryset is `Person.objects.prefetch_related('grade_set')`.

My template is

```
{% for form in formset %}
    Object id: {{ obj.id }}
    {{ form.name }}
    {{ obj.grade_set.all|running_total }}
{% endfor %}
```

I know that `obj` is not defined, but I think it maybe will be possible to do something like this in the template:

```
{% for obj, form in object_formset %}
    Object id: {{ obj.id }}
    {{ form.name }}
    {{ obj.grade_set.all|running_total }}
{% endfor %}
```

Right now my formset only consists of forms, but I rather need an object list and create some forms from this object list. I could do a small hack by creating the forms and use the field names and input names and completely avoid Django's way of creating forms, but I think it will be stupid. There must be some other way.

Comment: Please include the model(s) and form(s) you are referring to; it's difficult to tell what you're referencing when it's so abstract.

Comment: Also, when you say "I need some field values from the queryset", do you mean that you need them in the view that processes the submitted form? Or in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

```
# somewhere in views.py...
people = Person.objects.prefetch_related('grade_set')
formset = # ...(create your modelformset)...
people_and_formset = zip(people, formset)

# somewhere in template.html...
{% for person, form in people_and_formset %}
    {{ person.id }}
    {{ form.name }}
    {{ person.grade_set.all|running_total }}
{% endfor %}
```

Having used [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), the `grade_set` of each `Person` will be found in the Queryset cache, and will not require another hit to the db.

Comment: This is great. The problem is that I use `UpdateWithInlinesView` from django-extra-views and I don't know how to change the inlines variable in `get_context_data`. Can you help me out? I have looked through the code at https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views/blob/master/extra_views/advanced.py for hours

Comment: I have tried many different things but I get the error `zip argument #2 must support iteration` with `kwargs['obj_and_formset'] = zip(queryset, self.get_formset_class())` and `formset = zip(queryset, inlineformset_factory(self.model, self.get_inline_model(), **self.get_factory_kwargs()))`

Comment: @Jamgreen Unfortunately, that is a completely different question from the one you posted, and I'm not familiar with the `django-extra-views` repository. You're also not showing any relevant code. You might want to open up a new question.

Comment: @Jamgreen zip argument #2 is a formset, which supports iteration. Are you sure you're not passing it an instance of `modelformset_factory`?

Comment: I edited `construct_formset()` to return `return zip(queryset, formset.forms)` and now it works. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Can I do something similar when having many foreign keys? Each object queries the database for each foreign key, so it makes hundreds of queries :(

Comment: @Jamgreen I'm glad you got it to work. Take a look at `prefetch_related` and `select_related`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related

Comment: Editing the `construct_formset()` method didn't do the work as `post()` uses the same method to validate it. I have also tried editing `get_context_data` without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the FormSet is derived from `BaseModelFormSet`, the form is a `ModelForm`, which exposes its database object as `.instance`. You can access it like so:

```django
{% for form in formset %}
    Object id: {{ form.instance.id }}
{% endfor %}
```